# Hibernate: session.merge doing insert instead of update?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange thing happening in my code.

I have used session.merge which on updating the master table should update the child table. But for me After master table is updated in my child table a new record is being created which i need to solve. Please guide. Where can be the problem?. Can it be the Entity File?

Please find the below code.

```
public void update(List print) throws DataAccessException {
        try {
            if (print != null && print.size() > 0)
                for (Object object : print) {
                   entityManager.merge(object);
                }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DataAccessException("HibernateException");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a persistent object? Does it have a valid `id`?

Comment: yeah Print is a persistent object(reference to master table) and with it i have the child table that needs to be updated.

Comment: Could you add the relevant entity classes?

Comment: what kind of objects contains print `List`?

Comment: i am adding the java file

Comment: You still need to show the entity you are calling merge on and give more information on what you are referring to by master and child.  Merge will do an insert or update depending on what it determines is needed, so if you are getting an insert, check that the instance passed in has an ID.  Where did the list come from?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve the issue. 
I solved it by adding `orphanRemoval` property to my variable. As there was no `orphanRemoval` property it was not deleting the earlier ones and so i was getting wrong data in my application. Below is the corrected code.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "printColor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
 private Set<PrintColorFormatter> printColorSets;
```